# Want to know if my jsp format is correct

Tags: jsp

I am trying to select a particular field from a table and pass the value from one jsp to another.My first jsp file is as follows

list.jsp

```
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
   <title>Insert title here</title>
 </head>
 <body>

   <form method="POST" action="/Spring/deletedpage.jsp">

   <table BORDER="1">
    <tr>
         <TH width="50">Id</TH>
         <TH width="150">First Name</TH>
         <TH width="150">Last Name</TH>
         <TH width="100">Money</TH>
         <TH width="50">Currency</TH>
     </tr>
     <c:forEach items="${userList}" var="person">
     <tr>
         <td><input type="checkbox" name ="id" value="${person.id}"> <c:out 
               value="${person.id}" /></td>
         <td><c:out value="${person.name}" /></td>
         <td><c:out value="${person.password}" /></td>
         <td><c:out value="${person.gender}" /></td>
         <td><c:out value="${person.country}" /></td>
       </tr>
      </c:forEach>
     </table>
     <input type="submit"> 
     </form>
         <input type="submit" value="edit"/> 

    </body>
   </html>
```

i am selecting a single id from the table and passing it to another jsp named deletedpage.jsp which is as follows

```
<html>
 <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
   <title>Insert title here</title>
 </head>
 <body>

  <%
     String id1=request.getParameter(id);
      int id2=Integer.parseInt(id1);
      System.out.println(id1);
  %>
 <form method="POST" action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/deletedpage/delete">

       <P>Are you sure you want to delete this user??</P>
       <input type="submit" value="Yes" />

   </form>
    <p> <a href="frm4.jsp">No</a></p>
  </body>
 </html>
```

but i am getting the error in the following line

```
 String id1=request.getParameter(id);
```

as

```
id cannot be resolved
```

Comment: you should have id between quotes like String id1=request.getParameter("id"); Moreover why scriplets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably want

```
String id1 = request.getParameter("id");
```

Your original code looks for a local variable named `id`, and such a variable is not defined.

That said, you shouldn't have scriptlets in JSPs. Use the JSP EL:

```
${param.id}
```

Comment: using the jsp el also saves about 4 lines there :)